# How extract the polyline length in PyQgis 3.0?

Tags: pyqgis-3

I wrote the following code in order to automatically extract the objects' length of a line layer, but I think the « measureLine » expression is not working. This expression works very well PyQgis 2.0. Is there a new expression in PyQgis 3.0 ?

```
def dist_seg(layer):
  L=[]
  features=layer.getFeatures()
  d = QgsDistanceArea()
  for i, element in enumerate(features):
    m = d.measureLength(element.geometry())
    L.append((i, round(m,1)))
  return L
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should use d.measureLength. I didn't test it. In meantime, you can try it, and on this are all changes in PyQGIS3:
https://qgis.org/api/api_break.html#qgis_api_break_3_0_QgsDistanceArea

Comment: Many thanks Neven. The correct expression is as follow:

Comment: m = d.measureLength(element.geometry())

Answer (score 2):

Try to replace

```
m = d.measureLine(element.geometry().asPolyline())
```

with

```
m = element.length()
```